# Render B&W image with antialiasing

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, cgcontext

iOS project. I'm loading a bitmap from resources using `[UIImage imageNamed:]`, it's a black-on-transparent monochrome PNG. I then cut it up with `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()`. I render it in the screen context by `[UIImage drawInRect]`.

The drawn image on the emulator looks slightly antialiased on a Retina screen and prefectly sharp with a regular resolution. How can I make it look antialiased on a regular resolution, too?

The allow-antialiasing and should-antialias flags on the context are both set to true. Allow-interpolation flag on the image is true, too. What's missing, please?

Comment: Create a demo project with a sample image and the rendering, upload it to a public site like DropBox, and add a small bounty to this questions, and you'll get your solution shortly thereafter.

Comment: Did you try drawing it on an uneven pixel?